# Broken Glass on Samsung Galaxy S4 with slightly bent frame

Tags: screen

So a few days ago I stepped on my Galaxy S4 on a hard tile surface, mainly around the home button. The digitizer and the lcd screen work just fine and I am able to use my phone normally. The glass on the lower section is shattered and the frame just below the home button is bent in. Not the main frame thats about 10mm, but the small outer frame that surrounds the display. This part appears to be plastic when chipped but it isn't.

Is there a way to repair this during the glass only replacement?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> It depends which frame was impacted. If it was the "thicker one" this
>   one is easily replaceable (though you have to remove pretty much
>   everything - there are videos on youtube). Of course if you have a
>   warranty sticker on one of the screws warranty goes bye, bye if you
>   remove it.
>
> If it's the "thinner" to the front the only way to fix this is to
>   replace the whole assembly - screen included which costs big (about
>   250 USD import). That's because the AMOLED is glued to that frame -
>   you'd have to unglue the glass, and unglue the screen which is
>   impossible without breaking it.

([Source](http://www.galaxys4forums.net/forum/12-galaxy-s4-help/1504-help-potential-galaxy-s4-frame-replacement.html#post17049))